# How to set a marker in Leaflet maps as a var when a marker is clicked on?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, leaflet

I've set a title to a marker by using the following code:

```
L.marker([53.8, -3.05], options={icon: rattlers, title:"test1"}).addTo(map);
```

However, I now need to set the title as a variable when the marker is clicked on -- each marker will have a different title and will load something different depending on the marker. To do this I've added the click feature and told it to call the function onClick:

```
.on('click', onClick);
```

onClick is:

```
function onClick(d) {
        var title
        var marker_title = "#" + d.layer.options.title;
        if ( $(marker_title) ){
       // Call up the video.
           alert("Marker ID is: " + marker_title);
       }
    };
```

However when ever I try it says;

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of undefined

but it is when it's hovered over the marker.

I've got a working JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vimiio/42pph/

However, you'll need to zoom out and head towards the UK as it uses your location to center the map.

Comment: `d.target.options.title.toLowerCase();` replace `layer` with `target`. http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/42pph/1/

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks so much! Been working on trying to do this for hours! +1